# Run .net core app as windows application and start at windows startup

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, registry

I have app wrote using .net core 2.2

I want to run it like windows application and start on windows startup.

Here is how I make it run as Windows app

[image]

How I can make it run at windows start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options here.

1. One is to add a registry key. (you should have permission for this)

   `RegistryKey registryKeyk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
               ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);`

   `registryKeyk.SetValue("AppName", Application.ExecutablePath);`
2. You can run the exe from Task Scheduler.

Comment: Where do I need to set registry Key?

Comment: I understood
I mean where Program.cs file, or where?

Comment: `Application.ExecutablePath` , what namespace is it?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Okay, so the first variant will make my app run auto at the start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215649/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-eugene-sukh).